# How to use functions from other swift files (same target) in same project

Tags: swift, file

Hey I have 2 Classes each in own swift file. Im basically doing this only to get a better overview in my Viewcontroller. Still, I need to get access to the data or call the func from other files in my view controller.swift file. Its in the same Target so I don't need to import it in my view controller file right?

If I do override the func viewDidLoad() I get an Exception so I guess I am only allowed to do it once (-> in my viewController.swift)

//ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{


    @IBOutlet weak var xMotion: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yMotion: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var zMotion: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lineChartView2: LineChartView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       timebuffer.append(Double(ts1))
       colors.append(UIColor.red)

       Graphen.customizeChart(values: buffer1.map { Double($0) })
       Graphen.filteredChart(values: buffer2.map { Double($0) })
       Graphen.multipleCharts()
}
```

//Graphen.swift

```
class Graphen : ViewController
{

    //creates Plot with specific numbers/data
    func customizeChart(values: [Double]){
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        for i in 0..<buffer1.count{//dataPoints.count
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry) }
        lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: nil)
        lineChartDataSet.circleRadius = 0.5
        let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
        self.lineChartView.data = lineChartData
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what Graphen is but I get the impression it should not inherit from `ViewController` since it is more of a helper class (?) and in your `viewDidLoad` method you need to create an instance of Graphen before calling `customizeChart()`. Maybe even you should have property of type `Graphen` in ViewController``

Comment: Graphen.swift if my file where I declared a function that draws a chart in my LineChartView. I want to have the declaration in Graphen.swift and use it in ViewController.swift like Graphen.[nameOfFunc] for example customizeChart.

Comment: Like I said, it should not be a sub class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad()` is a `lifecycle method` of a `UIViewController's instance`. Thus, it can be `overridden` in each `UIViewCiontroller` `subclass`, i.e.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //your code here...
    }
}


class Graphen : ViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //your code here...
    }
}
```

Now, you don't need to import any `file/class` as long as they are in the same `target`.

Now, since `Graphen's` `customizeChart(values:)` method is an `instance method`, so you need to create an `instance` of `Graphen` first and then use it to call its instance methods like so,

```
let graphen = Graphen()
graphen.customizeChart(values: buffer1.map { Double($0) })
```

Similarly call other `instance methods` of `Graphen`. Assuming that `filteredChart(values:)` and `multipleCharts()` are also `instance methods`, you can invoke them like,

```
graphen.filteredChart(values: buffer2.map { Double($0) })
graphen.multipleCharts()
```

Comment: `let graphen = Graphen()`, if you are doing this in the `ViewController` class then you are creating an instance of the subclass in the superclass and that doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: Right. I just explained how we can use `Graphen` anywhere not just in `ViewController`. Moreover, we don't know the exact use-case of the problem

Comment: But Graphen _is_ a UIViewController subclass, do you usually instantiate them as other classes in your code?

Comment: Don't we? When doing it programatically instead of using the storyboard?

Comment: I know that and it is hardly the same use case as being discussed here.

Comment: Also, I don't think anywhere in the answer I elaborated the usage of `Graphen` in the `ViewController`. OP might be the best person to clarify the use-case.